# How to install manually USB CDC ACM driver for Windows when it is not detected

Tags: windows, usb, drivers

How to install manually USB CDC ACM driver under Windows 2k and Xp, when it is not automaticaly detected

Regards

Answer (score 1):

- Using this non-free generic driver (http://www.thesycon.de/eng/usb_cdcacm.shtml)
- If you're *really* expert, meaning that you need to already know how to write .inf driver files, you can see how to link the already built-in library (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837637/en-us). By the way this task is absolutely non trivial.